# Linq C# Outer Join Mostrar los valores que no se encuentran en los campos a comparar

Tags: c#, linq, join

tengo la siguiente duda, espero me puedan ayudar.
Cuento con dos tablas, una de materias y otra que asigna las materias a los alumnos través de sus id. "No todas las materias tiene alumnos asignados."
Me piden mostrar con linq aquellas materias que no tienen alumnos asignados.
En sql lo haría con outer join pero en linq desconozco como hacerlo. tengo el siguiente código:

```
var matsin = from m in dbContext.Materias
                     join am in dbContext.AlumnoMaterias
                     on m.IdMateria equals am.IdMateria
                     where m.IdMateria != am.IdMateria
                     select new
                     {
                         Nombre = m.Nombre
                     };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tenes que hacer uso de `DefaultIfEmpty`

Proba lo siguiente

```
var matsin = from m in dbContext.Materias
                 join am in dbContext.AlumnoMaterias
                 on m.IdMateria equals am.IdMateria into mam
                 from am in mam.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where am == null
                 select new
                 {
                     Nombre = m.Nombre
                 };
```

La hice a ojo, si falla en algún lado, hazlo saber!

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, arrojó la información que necesitaba. Ya estoy estudiando el código. saludos